# HTML dropdown can't capture onChange() if there is only one value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am using Jquery, for selecting value of drop-down.

I need do do some action on `OnChange` event (`.change` in jQuery) , but if there is only one option in drop-down I am not able to capture it in `onChange` event.

My drop-down is formed dynamically, so don't know how many options I'll get how many options, but I am facing problem if there is just one option.
Is there any way to capture `OnChange` event for `<select>` with only one `<option>`?

Comment: You have an interface design flaw. If it's possible to have only 1 selection in the drop-down, then the drop-down is the wrong control for the job.

Comment: @Joel - Not really, there are cases where this is a correct approach. E.g: `Select Planet` and then `Select Moon`. That would occasionally vary the second dropdown between 0-63, with earth having only one option (unless you count Cruithne, which you shouldn't).

Comment: @JoelEtherton , dropdown is formed dynamically.

Comment: @Niklas: Yes, but in those cases, such an approach would eliminate the need for the onChange event.

Comment: @Debugger: If it's dynamically formed, then it should be simple to add a "filler" selection such as "Select One" or something that would necessitate an actual change.

Comment: Did you solve this issue or make any progress?

Comment: No , thinking of using jquery auto suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have an onchange event. Just have a function that gets called from onchange, and if there is only one item, just go ahead and call that function.

```
function populate() {
    //do work to populate #selector

    if($("#selector option").length == 1) {
        $("#selector").hide();
        workerFunction();
    } else {
        $("#selector").show();
    }

    $("#selector").change(workerFunction);

    //the following line of code will work like a default:
    workerFunction();
}

function workerFunction() {
    //put whatever used to be in your onChange function here
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, but you could also shorten it a bit - `$("#selector").change(workerFunction);`

Comment: Yeah man , I liked the answer.But it's also problematic when there are 10 options in select , first is the default one , and you need an action on first option's action.Thats why I was thinking of autosuggest or something.

Comment: @Debugger just have it automatically default to the first one. I entered a line of code that will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

onchange event occurs when the internal state of the element is changed. Since you have a dropdown with a unique value, its state is never changed so the event is not fired.

Comment: dropdown is formed dynamically , but i still need to follow functionality which I have done for selects which contains elements.

Comment: you can try adding a blur event handler for those dropdown with just one element, or add a null value "Select element" so the user can really change the value of your dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="checkboxThatUsedToBeASelect">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxThatUsedToBeASelect" name="checkboxThatUsedToBeASelect"  value="something" />
</label>

$('#checkboxThatUsedToBeASelect').change( function(){

});
```

Now you have a more user-friendly input, and it'll trigger the change when it is checked or unchecked. :D

Comment: dropdown is formed dynamically , but i still need to follow functionality which I have done for selects which contains elements

Comment: I'm a big proponent of using radio sets/checkboxes on selections of ten or fewer items. It's a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

How about a conditional event binder? Something like:

```
var changeHandler = function (method) {
    alert(method);
};
if ($('select option').length > 1) {
    $('select').change(function() {
        changeHandler('change');
    });
} else {
    $('select').click(function() {
        changeHandler('click');
    });
}
```

Comment: There is no problem getting value , but I need to operate on its onChange.

Comment: What do you need to do in the `onchange` event?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have a HTML error in your options tags.

In addition to that, in order to target something created dinamically with jQuery, you have to use delegators.

```
$('selector').change( function(e){...}); // without delegator
$('body').on('change','selector', function(e){...}); // with delegator, it detects even an element added dinamically
```

This said, you should be abble to detect on change for new and old elements

Answer (score -2):

.change looks for another inmate to switch places. in your case sadly, there is a home alone case and hence the event is not firing.

Comment: I like the comment , loks like I need to do Baby's day out now... ;-)